# Can't resize shrunken boot partition to fill empty space

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, display

I needed to make room on my Windows 7 partition to install a new program, so I did some searching on how to resize a partition and it told me to shrink the OSX side and then expand the Windows one into the free space from Windows.

That didn't work, so now I have a 245 GB boot partition (my main OSX one), then roughly 10 GB of free space, then a ~61 GB Windows partition.

I tried to just drag the corner down on the OSX partition and click apply, but all it does is unmount and re-mount Windows 7 without changing anything.

I don't really care whether I expand the Windows partition into the free space as I originally intended or just re-expand the Lion one into that dead space, but there's about 12 GB of space there that's not doing anything, and I'd like to use it.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot resize the boot partition while booted from it. Instead, boot from a Mac OS X install DVD, then run Disk Utility there to resize your boot volume.

Comment: Also note that you won't be able to resize the Windows partition "upwards". You can generally only resize partitions at their "end", not at their start.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to delete the Bootcamp partition using Boot Camp Assistant.
I had a similar problem, and Boot Camp Assistant didn't recognize any Bootcamp/Windows partition, but in Disk Utility, the size of total space of my 1 TB HD showed only 850 GB of total space. The other 150 GB (from a failed attempt to create a bootcamp partition) did not show in the Disk Utility or anywhere else.

Then, quite by accident, I created 2 additional partitions using the Disk Utility.  The total space of the 3 partitions showed as 850 GB. However, I then used the Disk Utility to delete the 2 additional partitions which I had created, and it allowed me to specify a resized single partition of 1 TB.  After I had deleted the 2 additional partitions and resized to a single 1 TB partition, the total available space showed up as 1 TB (or actually, 999.97 GB), which seems as though I recovered all of the unused drive space.  :)